# Excel VBA cannot get element and input data a website

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to write a VBA script to input keywords (For expamle: Amuse) into the following website's textbox "Map Positioning" and click "go" to search the place automatically.
[CentaMap](http://hk.centamap.com/gc/home.aspx?lg=en)

Here is the html script I found for the textbox

```
<INPUT onkeyup=searchBoxTextChanged(this.value); id=qbyid style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" maxLength=60 name=q autocomplete="off">
```

Knowing that the normal way to do is to use get element by id then input such data in it. However I am being stuck as I cannot get the textbox element with the following codes:

```
Sub SubCentalineAutomation()
    Dim myIE As InternetExplorer
    Const url As String = "http://hk.centamap.com/gc/home.aspx?lg=en"

    Set myIE = New InternetExplorer

    myIE.navigate (url)

    Do While myIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    myIE.Visible = True

    myIE.document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Amuse" 
End Sub
```

I tried to replace the codes by using getElementsById("qbyid") instead however VBA cannot find the element too.
Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs Reference to

- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

```
Sub SubCentalineAutomation()
    Dim myIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim frame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
    Dim inp As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement

    Const url As String = "http://hk.centamap.com/gc/home.aspx?lg=en"

    Set myIE = New InternetExplorer

    myIE.navigate (url)

    Do While myIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    myIE.Visible = True

    Set frame = myIE.document.getElementsByName("search")(0)
    Set inp = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByName("q")(0)
    inp.Value = "Amaze"
End Sub
```

Comment: Impressive! Thanks for your help=)

Comment: @Anyway20 Did it not solve your problem first. Any reason to unaccept it?

Comment: QHarr's answer took me one more step forward to  navigate into the first found result. However as you are the first one to answer my question precisely. I will put your solution as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

try `getElementById("qbyid")`, not `getElementsById("qbyid")`

Comment: Still doesn't work. I guess the website cannot simply use getElementsByName / getElementByID to get element. Can anybody go into the website and have a look for the html script?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the suggestion, without the map navigation you can use:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, searchTerm As String
    searchTerm = "Amuse"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", "http://hk.centamap.com/gsearch/paddresssearch1.aspx?lg=en&search=" & searchTerm & "&ck=gbase&ft2=", False
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

            With html
                .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                 Debug.Print html.querySelector("a").innerText
            End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

If you want to enter a value and then navigate to the first returned suggestion:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SubCentalineAutomation()
    Dim myIE As InternetExplorer, html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, frame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement, form As MSHTML.HTMLFormElement
    Const URL As String = "http://hk.centamap.com/gc/home.aspx?lg=en"
    Set myIE = New InternetExplorer

    With myIE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document
        Set frame = html.getElementsByTagName("frame")(1)
        Set form = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
        form.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Value = "Amuse"
        form.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set frame = .document.getElementsByTagName("frame")(4)
        Set frame = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0) 
        frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click

        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However the next step I want to do is to navigate into the first found result. Would appreciate it if you can show the way, thanks.

Comment: You want to visually navigate on the shown map or you want to find the homepage of that first result?